# SharePoint as cloud storage for a web system

Tags: storage

I am analyzing the use of SharePoint Online as cloud storage for a website in development. The main use of this is for Word and PDF Files.
The main functionalities that we need are:

- File Search
- Metadata
- version control

I am wondering how should I use the licenses in this case.

I pretend to have around 500 users, so I have too many questions, maybe you can tell me where is the best place for read about it.

Should I have a licence of Microsoft for each user?

Could I use one unique licence for the whole system? In this case, How I will see the change control functionality in my words files?
Could I use guest Access ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: May I ask why SharePoint as the storage system? Will you be leveraging content types, workflows, and other SharePoint features? Will users sign-into SharePoint and interact with items using SharePoint? Is this SharePoint Server or SharePoint Online?

Comment: @shufler We will not use content type, neither wokflows.
Primarly we will use control versioning, search by metadata, and in less importance the use of office online.

Answer (score 1):

> SharePoint supports intranet, extranet, and Internet applications
>   from a single, integrated platform. The specific licenses you need
>   depend on three factors: what capabilities are used, how SharePoint is
>   deployed, and where the system is hosted.
>
> SharePoint Online is licensed on a per-user basis. You can purchase
>   SharePoint Online as a standalone plan or included as part of Office
>   365 plans.

Source: [SharePoint 2019 licensing](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview)

For more information, best place is to visit Microsoft's products site.

Check below links:

1. [SharePoint 2019 licensing](https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview)
2. [Compare SharePoint Online options](https://products.office.com/en-in/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans)